# where is data pump option in oracle sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Although Oracle SQL Developer help has description on data pump, yet I could not find in UI of SQL Developer

Answer (score 4):

View - DBA

Add a connection.

Expand tree.

Look down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change View to "DBA". Then the "data pump" option will show up.